# If Then Else Statements ML

Tags: syntax, ml

For example

```
(...)  if a < b then let c = a in else let c = b in  (...)
```

In general Ocaml, is it appropriate to have a `let` statement within an `if`, then, `else`, sequence? The reason I ask is I receive an error stating that "else" is an unexpected token, however I do not see a way to execute the statement without it.

> Notes: a and b were previously defined as integers in the two lines
>   above.

This question is specific to OCAml syntax.

Comment: I saw this question, however the one I posted is more specific to OCaml syntax. Thanks!